# How to resize an image with imagemagick to show a horizontal margin if required

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm using imagemagick to resize photographs in my app, but I'm having trouble getting it to work as I need it to.

Can someone please help me come up with the right combination of option configurations to meet the following requirements:

- Images should be resized to 320x213:

  - Set the height to exactly 213px
  - If the image is smaller than 320x213, enlarge it
  - If the image is larger than 320x213, make it smaller
  - Preserve the aspect ratio of the image
- If the resized image is narrower than 320px:

  - center the image horizontally
  - add a background colour to the back of the image
  - preserve the aspect ratio of the image
- If the resized image is wider than 320px:

  - trim the additional pixels evenly from both sides

Comment: What is your ImageMagick version and platform? You may have to script testing for the width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ImageMagick, try

```
convert image -resize x213 -gravity center -background white -extent 320x213 result
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!